# Java swing gui change background of jlabel and make it reset

Tags: java, image, swing, user-interface, panel

I have a gui that has: 
a label at the top
a JFrame at the bottom with 2 Buttons called left and right
a panel in center that is gridlayout with 2 JLabel to either display an image or change the back ground color. (currently the background color is set to black for both jLabels).

*what I would like to happen.

When you click on button "left" the image appears on lblPicture1 and lblPicture2 has a black background and no image. and vise versa for the right button. and when you click on the left again, it repeats this cycle.

I accomplish that however, when i click the left and right button I just have two images and neither one has a black background.

I belive this is due to the image not resetting.

Can you direct me to the right place on how I can get this to work?

Thank you

```
package gui;

import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.EventQueue;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.border.EmptyBorder;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.SwingConstants;
import java.awt.Font;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;

public class ExampleGUI extends JFrame {

    private JPanel contentPane;
    private JLabel lblPicture1;
    private JLabel lblPicture2;
    private int change;

    /**
     * Launch the application.
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                try {
                    ExampleGUI frame = new ExampleGUI();
                    frame.setVisible(true);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
    }

    /**
     * Create the frame.
     */
    public ExampleGUI() {
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setBounds(100, 100, 450, 300);
        contentPane = new JPanel();
        contentPane.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(5, 5, 5, 5));
        contentPane.setLayout(new BorderLayout(0, 0));
        setContentPane(contentPane);

        JLabel lblExampleGui = new JLabel("Example GUI");
        lblExampleGui.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(8, 0, 8, 0));
        lblExampleGui.setFont(new Font("Lucida Grande", Font.PLAIN, 24));
        lblExampleGui.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.CENTER);
        contentPane.add(lblExampleGui, BorderLayout.NORTH);

        JPanel panelButton = createPanelButton();
        contentPane.add(panelButton, BorderLayout.SOUTH);

        JButton btnLeft = createBtnLeft();
        panelButton.add(btnLeft);

        JButton btnRight = createBtnRight();
        panelButton.add(btnRight);

        JPanel panelCenter = createPanelCenter();
        contentPane.add(panelCenter, BorderLayout.CENTER);

        JLabel lblPicture1 = createLblPicture1();
        panelCenter.add(lblPicture1);

        JLabel lblPicture2 = createPicture2();
        panelCenter.add(lblPicture2);
    }

    public JLabel createPicture2() {
        lblPicture2 = new JLabel();
        lblPicture2.setOpaque(true);
        lblPicture2.setBackground(Color.BLACK);
        return lblPicture2;
    }

    public JLabel createLblPicture1() {
        lblPicture1 = new JLabel();
        lblPicture1.setOpaque(true);
        lblPicture1.setBackground(Color.BLACK);
        //lblPicture1.setIcon(new ImageIcon(ExampleGUI.class.getResource("/gui/schlange.gif")));
        return lblPicture1;
    }

    public JPanel createPanelCenter() {
        JPanel panelCenter = new JPanel();
        panelCenter.setLayout(new GridLayout(0, 2, 8, 0));
        return panelCenter;
    }

    public JButton createBtnRight() {
        JButton btnRight = new JButton("right");
        btnRight.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                //TODO
                lblPicture1.setBackground(Color.BLACK);
                lblPicture2.setIcon(new ImageIcon(ExampleGUI.class.getResource("/gui/schlange.gif")));
            }
        });
        btnRight.setFont(new Font("Lucida Grande", Font.PLAIN, 14));
        return btnRight;
    }

    public JButton createBtnLeft() {
        JButton btnLeft = new JButton("left");
        btnLeft.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                //TODO
                lblPicture2.setBackground(Color.BLACK);
                lblPicture1.setIcon(new ImageIcon(ExampleGUI.class.getResource("/gui/schlange.gif")));

            }
        });
        btnLeft.setFont(new Font("Lucida Grande", Font.PLAIN, 14));
        return btnLeft;
    }

    public JPanel createPanelButton() {
        JPanel panelButton = new JPanel();
        return panelButton;
    }

}
```

Comment: Call `setIcon(null)` on the label you would like to turn black

Comment: @MadProgrammer genius, I knew it was something simple thanks! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The background is painted beneath the `icon`, so if the `icon` is not reset, then it will continue to be displayed.

You can simply set the icon property by passing it `null`, for example

```
public JButton createBtnLeft() {
    JButton btnLeft = new JButton("left");
    btnLeft.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            //TODO
            lblPicture2.setIcon(null);
            lblPicture2.setBackground(Color.BLACK);
            lblPicture1.setIcon(new ImageIcon(ExampleGUI.class.getResource("/gui/schlange.gif")));

        }
    });
    btnLeft.setFont(new Font("Lucida Grande", Font.PLAIN, 14));
    return btnLeft;
}
```